# os python module making other code disfunctional

Tags: python

I am making a program that needs a way to create folders, but the only way I found is the OS module. However, it messes with the code that saves and writes to files. Example:

```
import os

# necessary code that creates folder
os.chdir("Example_directory/")
os.mkdir("New_folder_name")

# necessary code that writes to a text file
file = open("File_directory/document.txt", "w")
file.write("Text sample")
file.close()
```

And the error message is:

```
  File "C:\Users\First Name Last Name\Desktop\sample\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    file = open("File_directory/document.txt", "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File_directory/document.txt'
```

Even though the directory does exist.
and to prove the os module is the thing messing with the code, when I removed the os module and its block of code, I didn't receive any errors.

My main point is: Does anybody know an alternative way create folders in python?

Comment: Can you point to the point in your script which you believe should create `Example_directory/File_directory/`…?

Comment: `os.chdir()` changes the directory that all future pathnames are interpreted relative to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File_directory` presumably exists in the process's original working directory. But you changed its working directory with `os.chdir()`, and it doesn't exist in `Example_directory`.

There's no need to use `os.chdir()` before `os.mkdir()`, just create it as a subdirectory.

```
os.mkdir("Example_directory/New_folder_name")
```